# Is there a way to view the data stored by flutter_secure_storage package in web?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to view the data stored by flutter_secure_storage package in web? I know on mobile it uses keychain but I couldn't find any info related to web. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems flutter_secure_storage encode the value using an [algorithm](https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/blob/3bb93366161a787b07c45d8ce98c7405b40fbf1f/flutter_secure_storage_web/lib/flutter_secure_storage_web.dart#L135) & store the encrypted value on the local storage (found it on the [source code](https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/blob/3bb93366161a787b07c45d8ce98c7405b40fbf1f/flutter_secure_storage_web/lib/flutter_secure_storage_web.dart#L152C13-L152C13))